# UITable view, done button, remove effect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an UITableView. When the user clicks on Edit (to sort the items for instance) I enter in

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {
```

But when the user is done (and clicks on Done), there is a animation. How can I remove the animation which seems to reload the cells.

Thanks

EDIT : just figured out that this method is called again

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
```

is there a way to remove this call ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way :

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {
     if(editing)
       [super setEditing:editing animated:YES];
     else
       [super setEditing:editing animated:NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I meant the animation which appears AFTER the editing not on click on the edit button, but on click on the Done button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove that. When table view enters and exit from the edit mode tableView will automatically reloads the visible cells. That is actually an acceptable behavior editing mode is supposed to change something in the tabelView cells(insert or delete cells or edit some values). So inorder to reflect the changes you need to reload those cells. TableView will done the job for you. It will call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the visible cells

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the function you call on click of done

```
NSInteger rows;
rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
[tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```